# Making GUI for pyqgis console code?

Tags: pyqgis

I just finished my first ever code in QGIS using qgis stack and google. Now I want to make its UI so that my non-programmers can use it easily. I just walk through this guide ([Building a Python Plugin](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html)) but it is making plugin with external tools like [Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/index.html).

I want to ask you is there any direct UI making facility available in qgis through which i can run my console code or alternative any.?

Comment: What version of QGIS do you have installed?  I've always used QT Designer for UI configuration which comes installed with Q.

Comment: @artwork21
QGIS version
2.14.1-Essen

Comment: It should be located here, Designer.exe, C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\bin

Comment: its Qt Designer, so it is already shifted with QT framework also.

Comment: I second what @artwork21 has mentioned, Qt Designer is available to use to create a UI for your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my comment noted you may use QT Designer (Designer.exe, C:\Program Files\QGIS *versionName*\bin) (which comes installed with QGIS) to edit .ui form files.  Create a plugin using the plugin builder "plugin" and this will give you a template form .ui file which you may bring into Designer and edit and add your console code to the boiler .py it creates.

Comment: There is only Qt Designer available to develop GUI in qgis. m right